# What are the uses of tables version, version_commit and version_commit_date in shopware-6 database?

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, shopware

I am working on Shopware from version 5.x but now Shopware is updated to Shopware version 6.x. In Shopware 6 the number of database tables are less than Shopware 5 and has implemented some new concept as well. There are few completely new tables are added those are not available in Shopware 5. Whenever we perform any operation from admin panel like adding product, category or manufacturer for every action new rows are getting inserted in **version_commit and version_commit_date**, So my question is **why Shopware 6 is using these two tables?**

Answer (score 2):

these tables are used for versioning. This means, you could easily rollback your changes, or prepare special promotions/prices and switch them to live on a specific date. Note that not every entity supports versioning and not every possibility is provided with an UI in the administration panel.

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann